# "Unsatisfied dependency" warning when injecting Conversation into backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, intellij-idea, jboss7.x, cdi, jboss-weld

```
@ConversationScoped
public class BackingBean

{

    @Inject Conversation conversation;



    public BackingBean() {}



     ...

}
```

Why is Intellij giving me a warning: "Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point."

The CTRL+F1 detail message is "Detect injection points that have ambiguous dependencies."

It compiles and deploys and seems to run fine on JBoss e.g. I'm able to conversation.begin(), conversation.end(), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to Project Structure --> Modules. I selected my web module.  I noticed the CDI facet.  I clicked on the facet and noticed that neither of the two radio buttons were selected: Apache Open Web Beans or JBoss Weld.  I selected JBoss Weld.  Then, an error message appeared:

"The following libraries are missing: weld-api.jar, weld-core.jar, weld-logger.jar, weld-se.jar, weld-servlet-int.jar, weld-spi.jar, weld-tomcat-support.jar, weld-wicket.jar"

I clicked the "Fix" button.  A dialog opened, "Setup Library."  I had a choice: "Use Library" or "Download."

I chose Download.

Intellij downloaded the eight jar files and installed them in my $PROJECT_HOME/lib directory.

Now, I don't receive any warnings when I inject Conversation.

Answer (score 1):

If it runs on the server you are fine - looks like you either found a bug in Idea or somehow misconfigured the CDI nature of the project (`Conversation` is certainly in your classpath, but maybe not scanned by Idea)...

I suspect the latter :)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that, clearly, Conversation must have been in my classpath because the project compiled and ran fine after deployment.  That was the reminder that I needed to resolve the problem.  After thinking about it I realized that placing the dependency in my POM wasn't good enough; I had to do something else.  I documented the solution in my answer.